# Script to group files by extension and unzip archives

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script to sort my files by extension and unzip archives. It works in simple cases, but I haven't tested it extensively. How can I make it more robust against the set of file names that may be present?

```
#!/bin/bash
#File sorter
SECONDS=0
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
echo "trigger took place in $(pwd)"
for i in $( ls -1); do
  echo "processing $i ..."
  fileext=${i##*.}
  case ${i##*.} in
    zip)
      mkdir archive
      mkdir $(pwd)/archive/${i%%.*}
      unzip $i -d $(pwd)/archive/${i%%.*}
      ;;
    *) echo "nonzip"
      mkdir ${i##*.}
      mv $i $(pwd)/${i##*.}
      ;;
  esac
done
echo "Done in $SECONDS seconds!"
```

Comment: Given that two of us have posted a review of your code, I'm going to suggest that this question be migrated to [codereview.se]. Do not repost there! Once you've figured out what you wanted to do with ask, please ask a new question here on [unix.se].

Comment: I've edited your question to make it fit the CR format better, because I think that's what would benefit you most at this point. Please do come back here on [unix.se] to ask about that report in awk.

Comment: @Gilles I wanted to ask how I can generate report. So you mean, I should not attach my codes since that would be counted as code review? I attached the codes so I would give more explanation on what I actually do. But thank, I have got some really good comments about the codes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see where awk fits in this. I'm going to point out a few problems in your script, so you'll at least get something useful out of this. But please do tell us what you're actually trying to do.

> ```
> IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
> ```

There's a simpler way of writing that in bash: `IFS=$'\n\b'`. I don't understand why you're setting `$IFS` to include a backspace character; and whatever need you may have found to set `IFS` is probably caused by other problems that I'll point out below.

> ```
> echo "trigger took place in $(pwd)"
> ```

There's a variable `$PWD` that contains the current working directory. `$PWD` is equivalent to `$pwd` and a little faster.

> ```
> for i in $( ls -1); do
> ```

[Do not parse the output of `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) `ls` is a tool for displaying the attributes of files. The shell has a perfectly good construct for listing files in a directory: wildcards. Make this `for i in *; do …` This way has the advantage that it can cope with arbitrary file names; parsing the output of `ls` will always choke on some “strange” file names.

> ```
> fileext=${i##*.}
> ```

You should use this variable below.

> ```
> mkdir archive
> ```

If you run this part multiple times, the directory will already exist. Test for the directory's existence first, or call `mkdir -p archive`.

> ```
> mkdir $(pwd)/archive/${i%%.*}
> ```

Again, `$PWD`. Except that there's no point in using it, a relative path would do. Also, you need double quotes around all variable and command substitutions; otherwise the shell splits the result of the substitution at `$IFS` characters, then interprets the pieces as glob patterns (file name wildcards) and expands them. **Always put double quotes around variable and command substitutions** unless you know why you need to leave them off.

Another point: `${i%%.*}` strips everything after the first `.` in the file name. This is not compatible with the definition of `$fileext`. To get the file except for its last extension, use `${%.*}` (truncate at the last `.`).

> ```
> $(unzip $i -d $(pwd)/archive/${i%%.*})
> ```

I don't know what you're trying to do here, interpreting the output of `unzip` as a shell snippet. Again, double quotes around variable substitutions.

> ```
>   mkdir ${i##*.}
> ```

Again, double quotes. Also, if the file name sans prefix happens to begin with a `-`, the `mkdir` command will interpret its argument as an option. To avoid this, use `--` to indicate the end of the option list (this is a convention that most utilities respect): `mkdir -- "${i##*.}"`

Also, there's a case you don't handle: what if the file name contains no `.`? In that case, `mkdir` will attempt to overwrite the file (and fail). One solution is to create the directory with a temporary name, move the file, then rename it.

Here's the fixed code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#File sorter
set -e    # Abort in case of error
SECONDS=0
SAVEIFS=$IFS
echo "trigger took place in $PWD"
for i in *; do
  echo "processing $i ..."
  case $i in
    *.zip)
      [ -d archive ] || mkdir archive
      mkdir "archive/${i%.*}"
      unzip -d "archive/${i%.*}" "./$i";;
    *.*)
      mkdir -p "${i##*.}"
      mv -- "$i" "${i##*.}/";;
    *)
      tmp=$(TMPDIR=. mktemp -d)
      mv -- "$i" "$tmp/"
      mv -- "$tmp" "$i";;
  esac
done
echo "Done in $SECONDS seconds!"
```

Comment: P.S. I haven't tested the resulting code, there may be remaining bugs.

Comment: +1 nice explanation. You don't need the SAVEIFS variable now that you no longer change IFS.

Comment: @Gilles WOW. Thank man I really really appreciate what you did. Let me clarify what I want to do. I want to make directory for every file's extension that is present in $PWD and move the file there. Except if it is a zip file I want to extract it to the directory archive. I needed to overwrite $IFS since the filenames with spaces was counted as multiple files in the loop. And I needed to generate a report of what file moved/extracted where after it finished its process. That is why I wanted to use AWK. I hope I explained well what I want to do. Thank you really much for what you said so far.

Comment: @Erfan Please post a new question on [unix.se] explaining what you want in that report. What you wrote in your comment here is a good start; an example report for a couple of input files would help a lot.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks man. I actually got what I need just a simple text report and I made it. I just have only 1 problem and I really do not have a clue how to do it. I want to pass command arguments along with my shell script. For example the user would be able to write `sh fsorter.sh -d /Downloads` and the script runs in Downloads. Or some other ones. Can you help me understand where to start?

Comment: @Erfan Again, please ask on [unix.se]..

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you want to use awk, or what kind of report you want to see. I have made some code-review-type adjustments to your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# sort files into subdirectories
start=$SECONDS                    # this is a magic bash variable
echo "trigger took place in $PWD"
for file in *; do                 # don't need to call ls
  echo "processing $file ..."
  fileext=${file##*.}             # if you define a variable, you might as well use it
  case $fileext in
  zip)
    dirname=archive/${file%.*}
    mkdir -p "$dirname"           # make the parent and the subdir in one call
    unzip "$file" -d "$dirname"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "nonzip"
    mkdir -p "$fileext"           # -p option suppresses error message if dir exists
    mv "$file" "$fileext"
    ;;
  esac
done
echo "Done in $((SECONDS-start)) seconds!"
```

If you have any questions, please add a comment.

Comment: Looks like we had the same leaning. I caught a few more bugs. `SECONDS` would work as intended in the original, it can be assigned to.